# InstructionError: [ 0, 'ComputationalBudgetExceeded' ] Program failed to complete

Tags: spl-token, metaplex, nft, pda

```
//lib.rs code

use anchor_lang::prelude::*;

pub mod mint;
pub mod sell;
//pub mod swap;

use mint::*;
use sell::*;
//use swap::*;

declare_id!("H5sYvvHMEVSJb2QEwrhCmxGKsMHuntiWz3bmVfxUcBnt");

#[program]
pub mod nft {
 use super::*;

 pub fn mint(
     ctx: Context<MintNft>,
     creator_key: Pubkey,
     metadata_title: String,
     metadata_symbol: String,
     metadata_uri: String,
 ) -> Result<()> {
     mint::mint(ctx, creator_key, metadata_title, metadata_symbol, metadata_uri)
 }


 pub fn sell(ctx: Context<SellNft>, sale_lamports: u64) -> Result<()> {
     sell::sell(ctx, sale_lamports)
 }


}
```

// mint.rs code

```
use {
    anchor_lang::{
        prelude::*,
        solana_program::program::invoke,
        system_program,
    },
    anchor_spl::{
        associated_token,
        token,
        token::{Token, InitializeMint, MintTo, Transfer},
    },
    mpl_token_metadata::{
        ID as TOKEN_METADATA_ID,
        instruction as token_instruction,
        instruction:: {create_metadata_accounts_v3}
    },
};


    pub fn mint(
        ctx: Context<MintNft>, 
        creator_key: Pubkey,
        metadata_title: String, 
        metadata_symbol: String, 
        metadata_uri: String,

    ) -> Result<()> {

        msg!("Creating mint account...");
        msg!("Mint: {}", &ctx.accounts.mint.key());
        system_program::create_account(
            CpiContext::new(
                ctx.accounts.token_program.to_account_info(),
                system_program::CreateAccount {
                    from: ctx.accounts.mint_authority.to_account_info(),
                    to: ctx.accounts.mint.to_account_info(),
                },
            ),
            10000000,
            82,
            &ctx.accounts.token_program.key(),
        )?;

        msg!("Initializing mint account...");
        msg!("Mint: {}", &ctx.accounts.mint.key());
        token::initialize_mint(
            CpiContext::new(
                ctx.accounts.token_program.to_account_info(),
                token::InitializeMint {
                    mint: ctx.accounts.mint.to_account_info(),
                    rent: ctx.accounts.rent.to_account_info(),
                },
            ),
            0,
            &ctx.accounts.mint_authority.key(),
            Some(&ctx.accounts.mint_authority.key()),
        )?;

        msg!("Creating token account...");
        msg!("Token Address: {}", &ctx.accounts.token_account.key());    
        associated_token::create(
            CpiContext::new(
                ctx.accounts.associated_token_program.to_account_info(),
                associated_token::Create {
                    payer: ctx.accounts.mint_authority.to_account_info(),
                    associated_token: ctx.accounts.token_account.to_account_info(),
                    authority: ctx.accounts.mint_authority.to_account_info(),
                    mint: ctx.accounts.mint.to_account_info(),
                    system_program: ctx.accounts.system_program.to_account_info(),
                    token_program: ctx.accounts.token_program.to_account_info(),
                },
            ),
        )?;

        msg!("Minting token to token account...");
        msg!("Mint: {}", &ctx.accounts.mint.to_account_info().key());   
        msg!("Token Address: {}", &ctx.accounts.token_account.key());     
        token::mint_to(
            CpiContext::new(
                ctx.accounts.token_program.to_account_info(),
                token::MintTo {
                    mint: ctx.accounts.mint.to_account_info(),
                    to: ctx.accounts.token_account.to_account_info(),
                    authority: ctx.accounts.mint_authority.to_account_info(),
                },
            ),
            1,
        )?;

        msg!("Creating metadata account...");
        msg!("Metadata account address: {}", &ctx.accounts.metadata.to_account_info().key());


        let creator = vec![
            mpl_token_metadata::state::Creator {
                address: creator_key,
                verified: false,
                share: 100,
            },
            mpl_token_metadata::state::Creator {
                address: ctx.accounts.mint_authority.key(),
                verified: false,
                share: 0,
            },
        ];

        invoke(
            &create_metadata_accounts_v3(
                TOKEN_METADATA_ID, 
                ctx.accounts.metadata.key(), 
                ctx.accounts.mint.key(), 
                ctx.accounts.mint_authority.key(), 
                ctx.accounts.mint_authority.key(), 
                ctx.accounts.mint_authority.key(), 
                metadata_title, 
                metadata_symbol, 
                metadata_uri, 
                Some(creator),
                1,
                true, 
                false, 
                None, 
                None,
                None,
            ),
            &[
                ctx.accounts.metadata.to_account_info(),
                ctx.accounts.mint.to_account_info(),
                ctx.accounts.token_account.to_account_info(),
                ctx.accounts.mint_authority.to_account_info(),
                ctx.accounts.rent.to_account_info(),
            ],
        )?;

        msg!("Creating master edition metadata account...");
        msg!("Master edition metadata account address: {}", &ctx.accounts.master_edition.to_account_info().key());
        invoke(
            &token_instruction::create_master_edition_v3(
                TOKEN_METADATA_ID, 
                ctx.accounts.master_edition.key(), 
                ctx.accounts.mint.key(), 
                ctx.accounts.mint_authority.key(), 
                ctx.accounts.mint_authority.key(), 
                ctx.accounts.metadata.key(), 
                ctx.accounts.mint_authority.key(), 
                Some(0),
            ),
            &[
                ctx.accounts.master_edition.to_account_info(),
                ctx.accounts.metadata.to_account_info(),
                ctx.accounts.mint.to_account_info(),
                ctx.accounts.token_account.to_account_info(),
                ctx.accounts.mint_authority.to_account_info(),
                ctx.accounts.rent.to_account_info(),
            ],
        )?;

        msg!("Token mint process completed successfully.");

        Ok(())
    }

#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct MintNft<'info> {
    /// CHECK: We're about to create this with Metaplex
    #[account(mut)]
    pub metadata: UncheckedAccount<'info>,
    /// CHECK: We're about to create this with Metaplex
    #[account(mut)]
    pub master_edition: UncheckedAccount<'info>,
    #[account(mut)]
    pub mint: Signer<'info>,
    /// CHECK: We're about to create this with Anchor
    #[account(mut)]
    pub token_account: UncheckedAccount<'info>,
    #[account(mut)]
    pub mint_authority: Signer<'info>,
    pub rent: Sysvar<'info, Rent>,
    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
    pub token_program: Program<'info, token::Token>,
    pub associated_token_program: Program<'info, associated_token::AssociatedToken>,
    /// CHECK: Metaplex will check this
    pub token_metadata_program: UncheckedAccount<'info>,
}
```

//test-mint code

```
import * as anchor from "@coral-xyz/anchor";
import { Nft } from "../target/types/nft";

import { assert } from "chai";


describe("nft", async () => {

  const testNftTitle = "Chai";
  const testNftSymbol = "Gulab";
  const testNftUri = "https://github.com/Coding-and-Crypto/Rust-Solana-Tutorial/blob/master/nfts/mint-nft/assets/example.json";

  const provider = anchor.AnchorProvider.env()
  const wallet = provider.wallet as anchor.Wallet;
  anchor.setProvider(provider);


  const program = anchor.workspace.Nft as anchor.Program<Nft>;

  const TOKEN_METADATA_PROGRAM_ID = new anchor.web3.PublicKey(
    "metaqbxxUerdq28cj1RbAWkYQm3ybzjb6a8bt518x1s"
  );

  const mintFungibleAmount = 1 * anchor.web3.LAMPORTS_PER_SOL;


  let associatedTokenAccount = undefined;


  it("Mint!", async () => {

    // Derive the mint address and the associated token account address

    const mintKeypair: anchor.web3.Keypair = anchor.web3.Keypair.generate();
    const tokenAddress = await anchor.utils.token.associatedAddress({
      mint: mintKeypair.publicKey,
      owner: wallet.publicKey
    });
    console.log(`New token: ${mintKeypair.publicKey}`);

    // Derive the metadata and master edition addresses

    const metadataAddress = (await anchor.web3.PublicKey.findProgramAddress(
      [
        Buffer.from("metadata"),
        TOKEN_METADATA_PROGRAM_ID.toBuffer(),
        mintKeypair.publicKey.toBuffer(),
      ],
      TOKEN_METADATA_PROGRAM_ID
    ))[0];
    console.log("Metadata initialized");

    const masterEditionAddress = (await anchor.web3.PublicKey.findProgramAddress(
      [
        Buffer.from("metadata"),
        TOKEN_METADATA_PROGRAM_ID.toBuffer(),
        mintKeypair.publicKey.toBuffer(),
        Buffer.from("edition"),
      ],
      TOKEN_METADATA_PROGRAM_ID
    ))[0];
    console.log("Master edition metadata initialized");

    // Transact with the "mint" function in our on-chain program
    
    try {
      const tx =  await program.methods.mint(
      mintKeypair.publicKey, testNftTitle, testNftSymbol, testNftUri
      )
      .accounts({
        masterEdition: masterEditionAddress,
        metadata: metadataAddress,
        mint: mintKeypair.publicKey,
        tokenAccount: tokenAddress,
        mintAuthority: wallet.publicKey,
        tokenMetadataProgram: TOKEN_METADATA_PROGRAM_ID,
      })
      .signers([mintKeypair])
      .rpc({
        skipPreflight: true,
      });

    } catch (error) {
      console.error("error",error)
    }
  })

})
```

/// dependencies

> anchor-lang = { version = "0.26.0", features = ["init-if-needed"]}
> anchor-spl = {version = "0.26.0",features = ["metadata"]}
> mpl-token-metadata = { version = "=1.9.0", features = ["no-entrypoint"] }
> solana-program = "=1.14.13"
> winnow="=0.4.1"
> toml_datetime="=0.6.1"
> spl-token-swap = { version="3.0.0", features = [ "no-entrypoint" ] }

/// test script
test-mint = "yarn run ts-mocha -p ./tsconfig.json -t 1000000 tests/**/test-mint.ts"

i run with anchor run test-mint

Answer (score 4):

Follow this [tutorial to request extra compute budget for your transaction](https://solanacookbook.com/references/basic-transactions.html#how-to-change-compute-budget-fee-priority-for-a-transaction). :)

```
const modifyComputeUnits = ComputeBudgetProgram.setComputeUnitLimit({ 
  units: 1000000 
});

const addPriorityFee = ComputeBudgetProgram.setComputeUnitPrice({ 
  microLamports: 1 
});

const transaction = new Transaction()
.add(modifyComputeUnits)
.add(addPriorityFee)
.add(
    SystemProgram.transfer({
      fromPubkey: payer.publicKey,
      toPubkey: toAccount,
      lamports: 10000000,
    })
  );
```

Comment: This is good but please include the relevant code from links in your answer.